# Rails Testing System Stack Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rcov

I resumed testing my rails app after suspending it. Running tests on my rails app returns a SystemStackError now. Even a simple test like

def test_per_page

assert_instance_of Fixnum, Activity.per_page

end

is giving me

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/m
odule/introspection.rb:74:in `local_constants': stack level too deep (SystemStac
kError)

```
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:73:in `select'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:73:in `local_constants'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:86:in `local_constant_names'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:531:in `new_constants_in'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:525:in `collect'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:525:in `new_constants_in'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/plugin/locator.rb:89:in `plugins'
  ... 12095 levels...
 from ./unit/../test_helper.rb:2
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
 from unit/my_test.rb:1
```

I found that we had test-unit gem installed and removed it.. Even after that the same problem keeps popping up. I have rcov installed and same thing while using rcov also..

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:666:in `hash': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

```
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `inject'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:664:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:664:in `inject'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:664:in `hash'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:219:in `[]='
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:219:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     ... 12099 levels...
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rcov-0.8.1.2.0-x86-mswin32/bin/rcov:554:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rcov-0.8.1.2.0-x86-mswin32/bin/rcov:554
    from C:/Ruby/bin/rcov:19:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby/bin/rcov:19
```

Has anyone ever ran into something like this before.. I understand that the gem require is getting called over and over again.. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I tried creating a new project and writing a simple unit test on the same system and it worked like a charm... So i am guessing the problem is with one of the plugins that i have installed..

Also everytime i start to run tests this warning comes first..


C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:99:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement


I updated the gems using gem update --system and still its giving me the same error.. 

Thanks in advance for all help...

Answer (score 0):

Ooops! I had two initializers running for rcov when the environment gets started. One in the environment.rb file and another in the separate test.rb file in the env sub-folder in the config folder. So it kept on going on and on in a continuous loop.. Anyway problem solved and the Earth is still revolving.

Thanks